# URL hash to set select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a filter on a page consisting of 3 select dropdown's. When a value in each dropdown is selected, it's added to the URL, so it now looks like this:

```
domain.com/page#filter-1=.class1&filter-2=.class2&filter-3=.class3&
```

filter-1 is the id of the select, so filter-1=.class1 should select the option value .class1 in the filter-1 select and likewise for each select. But I just don't know how.

I have my URL hash in a var called hashFilter.

A simplified example

```
<select class="filter_select" id="filter-1" role="group" data-filter-group="filter-1">
    <option class="filter_select_option" data-filter="">Show all</option>
    <option class="filter_select_option" data-filter=".class-1" value=".class-1">Option 1</option>
    <option class="filter_select_option" data-filter=".class-2" value=".class-2">Option 2</option>
    <option class="filter_select_option" data-filter=".class-3" value=".class-3">Option 3</option>
    <option class="filter_select_option" data-filter=".class-4" value=".class-4">Option 4</option>  
</select>

<select class="filter_select" id="filter-2" role="group" data-filter-group="filter-2">
    <option class="filter_select_option" data-filter="">Show all</option>
    <option class="filter_select_option" data-filter=".class-1" value=".class-1">Option 1</option>
    <option class="filter_select_option" data-filter=".class-2" value=".class-2">Option 2</option>
    <option class="filter_select_option" data-filter=".class-3" value=".class-3">Option 3</option>
    <option class="filter_select_option" data-filter=".class-4" value=".class-4">Option 4</option>  
</select>

<select class="filter_select" id="filter-3" role="group" data-filter-group="filter-3">
    <option class="filter_select_option" data-filter="">Show all</option>
    <option class="filter_select_option" data-filter=".class-1" value=".class-1">Option 1</option>
    <option class="filter_select_option" data-filter=".class-2" value=".class-2">Option 2</option>
    <option class="filter_select_option" data-filter=".class-3" value=".class-3">Option 3</option>
    <option class="filter_select_option" data-filter=".class-4" value=".class-4">Option 4</option>  
</select>
```

I can set a select with e.g.:

```
jQuery("#filter-1").val('class-1');
```

But I don't know how to do it with multiple selects dynamically. 
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the value of of specific filter, use the `id` attribute in the selector

```js
jQuery("#filter-1 option:selected").text()
```

if you want all values of all filters, use the `class` attribute in the selector

```js
jQuery(".filter_select option:selected")
```

if you would like to dynamically pick one value from the selection based on the url, you will have to first parse the url, then use the parsed values to set the selection. for instance:

```js
# naievely parse the url
const map = window
  .location
  .hash
  .slice(1,-1)
  .split('&')
  .reduce((map, element) => {
    const [key, val] = element.split('=');
    map[key] = val;
    return map;
  }, {})

# set selection
  for (const [filterId, value] of Object.entries(map))
    jQuery(`#${filterId}`).val(value);
```

Comment: Or use the `.val()` method on the `"#filter-1"` selector.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain well enough. I need to set all 3 selects based on the URL hash, but I don't know how. In PHP I would build an array and iterate over it, but my javascript skills are not very good...

Comment: @Dyvel: this is not in your original question. once your have the values in hand, you can construct a string that represents the address that you neeed.

Comment: @Mr. I was what I was trying to explain in this sentence: "filter-1 is the id of the select, so filter-1=.class1 should select the option value .class1 in the filter-1 select and likewise for each select. But I just don't know how." But I do have the values in the URL and at hand in a var with the values that is added to the URL. Example: "filter-1=.class1,filter-2=.class2,filter-3=.class3,"

Comment: @Dyvel: i've updated my answer. hope it'll help you